# Get Json instead of XML from Nuget.Server

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nuget-server

I have setup a Nuget.Server to host a private nuget feed. I am trying to access that feed via the API however I can't convince it to give me json instead of XML.

My client code is as follows:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var packagesResult = client.GetAsync("http://localhost:61654/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id=\'Moq'").Result;

Console.WriteLine(packagesResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

I have checked the Formatters from the App_Start

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters
```

There are four formatters and the frist one is json.

How can I get the API to return json instead of XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your code. But, it seems that you are calling Nuget API V2 that only supports XML. You can check the response content type.

```
Content-Type: application/atom+xml; type=feed; charset=utf-8
```

If you'd like to get the API to return JSON instead of XML, use Nuget API V3.

API definition: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Sample: https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3/moq/index.json

Comment: I'm using Nuget.Server (https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Server) which only supports the V2 api. There is no host your own nuget server option which supports the V3 API that I could find.